# How to use the IN clause for multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-in

I am using Postgres and I would like to put together the following sql queries

```
select * from t1 where type=57 and idt=2001 and date=1;
select * from t1 where type=59 and idt=2001 and date=1;
select * from t1 where type=57 and idt=2002 and date=3;
select * from t1 where type=57 and idt=2001 and date=2;
select * from t1 where type=59 and idt=2002 and date=1;
```

together in only one statement, like this:

```
select * from t1 where (type, idt, date) in 
{
(57, 2001, 1),
(59, 2001, 1),
(57, 2002, 3),
(57, 2001, 2),
(59, 2002, 1),
}
```

but I get the syntax error.

What's the correct syntax to achieve it?

Comment: Switch `{` to `(`, and see shat happens. And remove the last comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you find, that curly braces would be correct in this case?  Just use regular parentheses:

```
select * 
from t1 
where (type, idt, date) in (
                             (57, 2001, 1),
                             (59, 2001, 1),
                             (57, 2002, 3),
                             (57, 2001, 2),
                             (59, 2002, 1)
                           )
```

Comment: cool I didn't know we could do this directly with in. Slight correction, there is an extra comma at the end.

Comment: @CetinBasoz: the comma was a copy & paste error, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can join a table created with values clause, ie:

```
select t1.* from t1 inner join 
(values (57, 2001, 1),
(59, 2001, 1),
(57, 2002, 3),
(57, 2001, 2),
(59, 2002, 1)) as foo(type, idt, date)
on t1.type = foo.type and t1.idt = foo.idt and t1.date = foo.date;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=35db942d347872f10a1ed886ba971297)